# Android HLS - Where is the Source code?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I need to locate Google's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) source code for Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HLS code is implemented in a C++ library, which is why you probably couldn't find it with GrepCode.

The library is called **stagefright** and it's used by the java classes (MediaPlayer and so on) and then relies on other shared libraries to interface with hardware decoders.

You can find an overview of how it works in the android system [here](http://quandarypeak.com/2013/08/androids-stagefright-media-player-architecture/).

And the HLS-specific source code for the You can find the HLS-specific source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/httplive/) and/or [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/httplive/).